# How to read notifications on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to get a Python program to read Mac notifications.

I’ve tried a few things including using [Pync](https://github.com/setem/pync), then I took a look at [JxA](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224). But it  seems (at least what I've seen) everything only helps with creating notifications, not reading them.

Is there a way to read notifications? (If so, would it be possible to select notifications coming from a particular app that way?)